# Problema con select dependientes

Tags: php, ajax, poo

Tengo un problema tratando de anidar dos select, este es mi archivo hasta alli todo bien, si le doy un echo a la variable $datos me va mostrando el id del select que voy seleccionando ajax.php

```
public function obteneridpais(){
        $datos = $this->valor_id_pais;
        $respuesta=Controller::SelectCiudadescontroller($datos);

        echo $respuesta;
    }
```

el problema esta en cuanto deseo pasar ese valor a la funcion SelectCiudadescontroller,me muestra el siguiente error:

> ```
> <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function 
> Controller::SelectCiudadescontroller(), 0 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\views\modulos\form_registro_usuarios.php on line 65 and exactly 
> 1 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\coffee\controller\controller.php:76
> ```

y esta es mi funcion:

```
public function SelectCiudadescontroller($valor_id_pais){

        $datosController = $valor_id_pais;

        $respuesta = Datos::SelectCiudadesModel($datosController,"ciudad");

        if(count($respuesta["id_ciudad"]) > 0){

            echo 0;

        }

        else{

            echo 1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Dónde llamas a la función `SelectCiudadescontroller`? El error es porque no recibe ningún parámetro

Comment: La llamo en el archivo ajax.php que desde alli voy a enviar el parametro a esa funcion

Comment: Sería bueno que también pusieras ese código en la pregunta para poder ayudarte

Comment: amigo @PauloUrbanoRivera el codigo esta comenzando de igual forma aca lo vuelvo a pegar

public function obteneridpais(){
   $datos = $this->valor_id_pais;
   $respuesta=Controller::SelectCiudadescontroller($datos);

   echo $respuesta;
  }

Comment: Pdrías verificar si la variable `$datos` en este fragmento de código `$datos = $this->valor_id_pais;` tiene el valor del pais; imprimiendo su valor antes de llamar al `Controller`

Comment: Si lo tiene amigo @CesarRomero, ya yo le di un echo y me muestra el id del select que estoy seleccionando

Comment: `if(count($respuesta["id_ciudad"]) > 0)` -> esta mal, `if(count($respuesta) > 0)` ->algo asi deberias de tener en **count**

Answer (score 0):

La condición de tu **if** esta mal,

> if(count($respuesta["id_ciudad"]) > 0)

Lo que debes de hacer es algo asi:

`if(count($respuesta) > 0)`

espero que te haya ayudado